# Importing matrix from one file to other using os.system

Tags: python

I want to import W matrix from script_1 to script_2. How can I do that?

## Script_1

```
`def main():
    W=W_fc.eval()
```

## Script_2

```
`from Script_1 import W
os.system("python Script_1.py")
print W`
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name W